# What are these straight bright lines in the negative and scans?

Tags: film, vintage, light-leaks

I ran a test roll of Fujicolor C200 through a newly acquired [Voigtländer Vito II](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Vito_II).

Upon closer inspection, all the photos have bright straight lines (take a look at the top 20% of the picture where the sky is):

Picture 1:
[image: picture 1]

Picture 2:
[image]

I also see these lines on the negative. I checked some similar questions, but these look different to me.

Is this a light leak from the bellows, something from the back plate, damaged film, human error, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The base side of the film is likely scratched. Could have happened in the camera. Check the film transport rollers and add a tiny bit of oil at spindles on their ends. The scratches could have been received during processing. A dirty roller on the film processor or if the negatives were printed at the lab, the printing machine might have scratched the film as the negatives were advanced at the film gate.

To verify, examine the negatives by reflective light. Check both sides for scratches.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I checked the film - the scratches are on the ‘front’ side (the side facing me if the frame numbers face the right way) - is that the base side?
I tried matching the scratches to the rollers and there’s nothing obvious there. I did get the negatives scanned by the lab too.

Comment: These scratches happened in the camera or at the lab..